# How can I get xrdp working with multiple monitors?

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I've seen these two resources:

1. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1168264
2. https://github.com/asafge/xrdp_dualmon

But it looks like #1 is out of date, and #2 has too many constraints (maximum resolution, limited size of desktop).

I was using NoMachine client/server for this purpose, but new versions of NoMachine's software don't permit this with their free versions.  (Maybe it's time to request a license?)  Also, our new officially sanctioned Windows boxes (the client) are locked down even more, so the client must be a portable app, i.e., doesn't require administrator privileges in order to be installed or to run.

Also, I did get the free portable version of NoMachine's NX client to connect to FreeNX on Linux, however [resuming sessions didn't work](https://bugs.launchpad.net/freenx-server/+bug/589723), which might be a deal-breaker.

Any other ideas for getting multiple displays to work between a Windows client and a Linux server?